# Capistrano picking up outdated commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab, capistrano3

I have a Rails 4 app that until now, has been deploying just fine. I use Gitlab.com private repo. I have not changed anything, and it is for some reason picking up an old commit from 8 months ago as the "latest".

The correct branch (`master`) has the latest changes pushed. Capistrano is deploying the master branch. In the browser, the master branch has the latest changes I made showing properly. I can continue to push other commits (my git config file is fine).

When I deploy, Capistrano for some reason thinks that the latest commit on master is `256f303` from 8 months ago, not `e948bfa`. If I go to the directory Cap just deployed on the remote server, the code is outdated (consistent with the state of the code as of `256f303`).

The Cap command `( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3 /usr/bin/env cat /home/project/deploy/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null )` returns the old commit SHA `256f303`.

- When I did `be cap production deploy revision=<full e948bfa sha>`, it had no effect. Still getting `256f303`.
- Removing or renaming `$deploy/repo` directory has no effect. It creates a new `repo` directory and the problem persists.
- Modifying the `repo/packed_refs` file such that `refs/heads/master` points to `e948bfa...(etc)` instead of `256f303...(etc)` gives the message `error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!`
- In `production.rb`, setting `set :branch, ENV.fetch('REVISION', 'master')` (instead of `set :branch, 'master'`) has no effect. Same with `set :branch, ENV.fetch('branch', 'master')`.

I'm absolutely baffled. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I've done what I can to figure out where this `256f303` is coming from. Is this a GitLab issue? Or on my end somewhere?

edit: not much of an update. I ended up recloning, and I'm not sure if that's what did it, but it's sorted now. I don't feel like it's a real answer, but there you go :)

Comment: I had same situation in passenger web app server. I solved this by removing all directory from the server. i,e : current, releases, repo, revisions.log file, shared. And deployed the new project. you can try this.

Comment: I'll do that if I'm desperate, I guess? I'd really rather not though, since it's a production box.

Comment: You don't need to remove the folders, just move them to a different place, like old_revisions, and try doing that. It looks like you tried the logical things to do. If after the move you still get the issue then it's something else.

Comment: Try running your deploy with -v flag, to see the output, maybe you will get more info.

Comment: This might go without saying, but try it with latest Capistrano, e.g. 3.9.0 at time of writing.

Comment: Thanks @will_in_wi - updated Cap to latest version. Same result (much nicer output tho, +1 :)

Comment: @Mugur'Bud'Chirica there doesn't seem to be a -verbose option that I can find. Cap 3 just gives me the version when I do that. I guess I have to just muck with the prod box and hope for the best :P

Comment: Sorry, bad command in my part. Use `cap deploy production --trace`, for more info about Capistrano options use `cap --help`.

Comment: I tried pushing a new branch called `deploy` - and it gives me `that doesn't look like a tar`. I deployed `master` to a brand new machine, and I still get `256f303`. I think this is a GitLab bug!

Comment: As Ajay, I had same situation in passenger web app server. I solved this by removing this directories: _current, releases, repo, revisions.log_ file but not _/shared_. It works.